# Concatenate two videos in shell_exec in php?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, concatenation, shell-exec

I am trying to concatenate two videos using `ffmpeg` in PHP. When I run this command in Terminal it works fine

```
ffmpeg -i concat:"1.mp4|2.mp4" -codec copy output.mp4
```

Then output is generated. When i try to implement in `shell_exec` its not working it returns empty string.
This is my code.

```
$s= shell_exec('ls cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/videoapp/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i concat:"1.mp4|2.mp4" -codec copy output.mp4');
echo "<pre>$s</pre>";
```

Inside the FFMpeg folder I am trying to put concatenated video so I chose the path ffmpeg folder. The remaining string `ffmpeg -i concat:"1.mp4|2.mp4" -codec copy output.mp4` for concatenate the video.

Comment: did you check the accessibility to write in that folder? Try "touch output.mp4"

Comment: First, is `shell_exec` disabled? Second, does PHP and/or the web server have privileges to execute the `ffmpeg` function?

Comment: Shell_exec is enabled , and i dont know how to set the privileges to execute the ffmpeg function in php

Comment: i tried this code "ls cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/videoapp/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i concat:"1.mp4|2.mp4" -codec copy output.mp4" in terminal in that also not working